# ArcMap Draw Camera Range with ArcPy

Tags: postgis, arcmap, arcpy, postgresql, polygon-creation

i am working on some camera data. I have some points which consist of azimuth, angle, distance, and of course coordinate field attributes. In arcmap I want to draw shapes like this:

[image: Sketch of angular sector]

The shape is pink.  Can I get the shape with postgres-postgis?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there must be a diagram missing from this question.

Comment: what diagram you need for this

Comment: Diagram is there now so not sure why it was not when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 2009 ArcGIS python script here: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16089

If you have the necessary attributes in your point feature class, then it is pretty straightforward and the script creates a polygon feature class.  You need a From azimuth and To azimuth so you might need to do some calcs on your table first.  It also uses a From distance and To distance, but from your diagram you probably want those two fields to be equal for each point.

The script creates a polygon for each point.  It doesn't have a smooth arc but the script creates polygon edges at 1 degree increments, so it's pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

ESRI just added a blog post and ArcGIS 10 tool for this problem here:
http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/mappingcenter/archive/2012/02/15/pie-sector-features-communicate-multivariate-data.aspx